# Let's talk abstract vs concrete

Tags: meaning, abstract-nouns

So I'm trying to clarify the extent of what abstraction means.

I understand it represents things like emotions or ideas that can't concretely be sensed, just abstractly discussed...but what if those abstract nouns affect the world around them concretely?  Things such as the stock market, or GDP, or academic subjects such as physics (which governs the expertise of the observable physical nature of the universe).

It seems to me something like physics could and should be considered 'more' concrete than something like math or english, despite it discussing the ideas/mechanics of observable phenomena.

Would these still be considered abstract even though they have very real, observably concrete effects on the society we live in?

Thanks in advance,

Just Curious.

Comment: Very many abstract nouns have real, observable effects. Is this a question about language or philosophy?

Comment: I was just wondering the extent that you would consider something concrete/abstract, and I needed a better understanding of the difference between the two to find the answer.  Lawrence answered my question pretty thoroughly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to think about this is to consider abstractions as models of reality.

The physics equation `F = ma` is a model that relates force, mass and acceleration. Now, even if we concede for the sake of argument that forces, masses and accelerations are concrete, one would be hard pressed to visualise the process of multiplying a mass with an acceleration. What we do instead is multiply a *measure* of the mass with a *measure* of the acceleration.

Maths and English are forms of communication. However, the content of the communication, such as symbols, equations, letters and paragraphs, bear very little resemblance to the things referenced by the communication, except perhaps when the things referenced are also abstract.

We can now discuss levels of abstraction. Consider an actual stone falling to an actual earth (concrete in the abstract sense :) ) to be level zero. We might then model the interacting objects by reducing them to (measurements of) some aspects such as mass and gravitational acceleration, ignoring others such as colour, ownership or history. Let's call this level 1. We now establish mathematical equations (level 2) relating measurements from level 1, and so on.

As the levels increase, the discussion becomes increasingly abstract. Conversely, as the levels decrease, the discussion becomes increasingly concrete.

You asked, `"Would these still be considered abstract even though they have very real, observably concrete effects on the society we live in?" The word "these" could be taken in several ways.

If we take "these" to mean physics, maths and English, I'd say they would, since each deals with levels above zero. You might even consider particular statements in any of those areas to be more abstract or less abstract than others.

If we take "these" to mean "abstract nouns" specifically, I'd still say they would. For example, GDP is a measure of the size of an economy. We might go from the (concrete noun) vegetable to its (abstract) monetary value, and on through aggregations to eventually reach the GDP. We might then correlate GDP other (abstract) measures of health, wealth, happiness, etc. We then follow (say) health back through its chain of abstraction to some concrete manifestation of a specific individual's well-being. At this point, although *GDP* might be said to "have very real ... effects", the concrete interaction is actually between the vegetable and the individual, not between GDP and the individual. Abstractions may relate to concrete effects, but that doesn't make abstract nouns concrete.